# How to avoid Show ¶ messing up the word wrap?

Tags: google-chrome, word-online, microsoft-365

This text is word-wrapped as expected:

[image]

until I Show ¶, which messes it up:

[image]

losing WYSIWYG at Print:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/rX9zpsi.png]

How can I avoid this?

This is on latest Windows Chrome. I don't know which version of 365, since I can't find a Help About box.

Comment: @Blindspots enabling Show ¶ creates mismatch between what Word shows and the actual printed document. I'm not surprised, I've had similar issues when printing to PDF.

Comment: @Blindspots the dot showing spaces could have used the same spacing as the actual spaces. The `¶` showing  new lines could have used the margin instead of overflowing to a new line. So in theory its possible to have the  printed document match the on-screen document (ignoring, of course, the non-printing information).

Comment: @Blindspots my point is that the extra non-printing information on the screen does not necessarily affect the layout of the document (see the two examples I gave in my previous comment). Therefore the question makes sense.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

> *This text is word-wrapped as expected
>
> until I Show `¶`, which messes it up
>
> losing WYSIWYG at Print
>
> How can I avoid this?*

## TL;DR

If you prefer WYSIWYG, don't defeat it by showing non-printing characters.

### Background

**Early** word processing applications required users to manually enter non-printing markup tags using application-specific syntax to format a document for printing. This meant what was displayed on-screen didn't match what was ultimately printed.  It is analogous to the tags in HTML, a web markup language, which contain instructions for formatting the content within the tags, however the tags themselves are not displayed when the page is rendered by a web browser.

**Modern** [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) ("What You See Is What You Get") word processing applications will hide non-printing markup and provide a more accurate on-screen representation of the printed document. To achieve this, the on-screen representation is married to printer drivers and because of this two users opening the same document can see a different layout, and even a single user may see layout changes when they print a document between different printers (including Acrobat PDF) because of the different drivers.

Some of the non-printing formatting marks hidden in WYSIWYG applications include Tabs, Spaces, Paragraphs, Hidden Text, Optional Hyphens, Object Anchors, Page/Section/Optional Breaks, and much (much) more.

## Show/Hide Formatting

While Word tries to provide an accurate on-screen representation of the printed document, users sometimes need to display non-printing information. It can simplify troubleshooting formatting or may be a personal preference.

Word provides a show/hide formatting **`¶`** toggle in the ribbon menu for non-printing formatting markup. There is also a keyboard shortcut **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>**

## Problem Space

If one chooses to show non-printing markup one can just as easily hide it to return the document to a more accurate representation of the printed version.

Displaying additional markup on-screen while also expecting to retain an accurate representation of the printed document is not reasonable, and the question is either impractical or lacks sufficient detail to be understood as a practical question.

## Show/Hide Non-Printing Character Examples

[image: Variable-Width Font]

[image: Variable-Width Font]